# Why data on device is soo high for nativescript apps?

Tags: nativescript

I created just basic app with two pages having one list array and item object but still when I see apps properties after `tns run android` command it says ~3.7MB for data on device and also app size is also ~20MB. Since its just a basic app its size should not have been this much.

Answer (score 0):

The application becomes this size because of the modules and libraries it uses. So far it doesn't matter how basic the application is, you have them by default.